Route53 base domain A-record not resolving in Web browser
Recently I migrated a domain (xyz.com) from SquareSpace to AWS Route53 along with all the records, Now all the records are working except for the base domain. It has a www.xyz.com C-Name as well which is also working fine, but xyz.com just doesn't seem to work with the IP address.

I have verified the IP address.
I have rechecked the NameServers between the NS records and the
registrar(AWS now in my case), they both match.
When I use tools like dig/mxtoolbox, the IP is getting resolved
along with all the nameservers.
I have added the TLS certificates for both www and base domain. Just
that when I open the base domain https:// xyz.com in browser, it
shows:


xyz.com unexpectedly closed the connection.


If you want help with this you should publish your actual domain name so we can look direct at it to see if there's a problem. You can edit it out later if you like. Please also edit your question to include screenshots of the DNS records, and give some idea of what is listening for the requests - eg Nginx on EC2, and you could include that configuration in case that's the problem.
